# customising the full calendar as in the picture attached

Tags: fullcalendar

[image]

Hi, I want to show my full calendar like this I am new to this, can any help me with this. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically need is to use the month view (it's the default view), like in the example: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/views/month/

You will also need to customize the event background color using the configuration 'eventBackgroundColor', see: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventBackgroundColor/

I suggest you the read the documentation. Some parts of what you want you will need to do it yourself using the methods provided by the API. Some other parts is ready-for-use.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your help , i customized my calendar till the month view of the calendar is appearing but i am unable to get the Holidays and events. please help me how to do that.

Comment: You can find everything you need about getting the events over here:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

Comment: hi @Pedro,  thanks for your help, I customized that using bootstrap portlets. i got it.